# How to save and return multiple objects using PUT and PATCH method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to update some records in a DB table using the Update API view which consists of PUT and Patch methods. Upon calling the API I'm getting `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one`  error.

Below are sample records that I'm trying to update.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 1.00,
    "spec_id": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 1.00,
    "spec_id": 6,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": 1.00,
    "spec_id": 6,
  },
```

I'm sending **spec_id** in **API** for ex:- `/api/specification/:spec_id/` and **payload** as {'value':2.00}, which will basically be used for updating the data on the basis of **spec_id** by querying in to the table.

Code to look data in the DB table based on spec_id and update all the records related to spec_id & return:

> views.py

```
class SpecificationUpdateAPIView(BaseAuthenticationMixin, generics.UpdateAPIView):

   serializer_class = SpecificationAdminSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
   lookup_field = "spec_id"
   queryset = Specification.objects.all()
```

> serializers.py

```
class SpecificationAdminSerializer(CreateUpdateModelSerializer):
    class Meta(CreateUpdateModelSerializer.Meta):
       model = Specification
       fields = ("id", "value", "spec")
```

> urls.py

```
    path(
    "api/specification/<int:spec_id>/",
    views.SpecificationUpdateAPIView.as_view(),
    name="specification-update-view",
     )
```

Could someone please help me resolve this issue, highlight the mistake I'm doing or navigate me to any other better approach to make this kind of scenario work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UpdateAPIView` is for single object, which calls `get_object` in update method, which is throwing exception as multiple records
are being returned from database. If you would like to update multiple records, you will have to customize the update function as below:

```
class SpecificationUpdateAPIView(BaseAuthenticationMixin, generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = SpecificationAdminSerializer
    lookup_field = 'spec_id'

    def get_queryset(self, spec_id):
        return Specification.objects.filter(spec_id=spec_id)

    def update(self, request, spec_id, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instances = self.get_queryset(spec_id)
        for instance in instances:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response({"status": "updated"})
```